# is it possible to import pdf and take certain data/content on the pdf using php

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I thing title is explaining my question. Will be realy great if there is possibility to do that. I was able to read pdf template using mpdf1 and tcpdf but I don't have any idea how to read the **certain contents** of the pdf template and keep them as php variables.

Comment: http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/ and http://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/pdf-import/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I am trying to take certain contents from the pdf files. The links aren't explain how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This library looks very promising for your task:

http://www.pdfparser.org/